# How to use Next JS IMAGE inside material ui card media

Tags: material-ui, next.js, nextjs-image

I am using Next JS and Material UI together in my project. for Image optimization, I would like to use the Next JS Image component.

currently, my card media looks like below. I am getting the image URL **row.image.url** from an API call and assigning it to the **image** prop of the **CardMedia** component

```
 <CardMedia
 className={classes.cardMedia}
 image={row.image.url}/>
```

But I would like to take the advantage of the Next JS **Image** component for the optimization and lazy loading but couldn't able to see a way to fit this.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
```

Did anyone face this type of requirement?
Appreciate your help

Thanks
Venk

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like this:

```
        <CardMedia className={classes.cardMedia} title="Your title">
          <div style={{ position: 'relative', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
            <Image src={row.image.url} layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
          </div>
        </CardMedia>
```

Check [this answer](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/23352) for more info

Comment: and you can use fill prop instead of layout which is depricated

Answer (score 1):

Objectfit is now deprecated and you should use the style prop in the Image component.

```
style={{objectFit: "cover"}}
```